# Table required Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, html-table

I want to validate the fields in a table so that they are not empty, and required

If empty, `*` should appear near that field.

Here is my code, it shows an `alert`, but I want to show a `*` next to the field instead of `alert`

HTML

```
<table id= "table1">
    <tr>
        <td id="t1">First coulmn</td1>
        <td id="t2">value2</td2>
        <td id="t3">
            <a id="Next" onclick= "javascript:validAndNext('1')">Save</a>
        </td3>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="tableN">
```

JavaScript

```
function validAndNext(table_id) {
    var table = $('#table'+table_id);
    var inputs = table.find("input");
    var valid = true;

    inputs.each(function() {
        // A type of validation is:
        if ($(this).val().length <= 0)
            valid = false;                
    });

    if(valid) {
        table.hide();
        $('#table'+(table_id+1)).show();
    } else
        alert('Your table is not valid!');
}
```

Comment: Need Clear description....

Comment: First column denotes td value or header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have

```
  <div class="error"></div>
```

at the end of the table,
then append the content inside using jquery.

```
   $('.error').append('Not Valid'); in else part.
```

Edited Code:

```
<table id= "table1">
  <tr>
<td id="t1">First coulmn</td1>
<td id="t2">value2</td2>
<td id="t3">
    <a id="Next" onclick= "javascript:validAndNext('1')">Save</a>
</td3>
</tr>
```

```
<table id="tableN">
<div class="error"></div>

    function validAndNext(table_id){
   var table = $('#table'+table_id);
   var inputs = table.find("input");
    var valid = true;
   inputs.each(function(){
     // A type of validation is:
   if($(this).val().length<=0) valid = false;                
    });
  if(valid){
     table.hide();
   $('#table'+(table_id+1)).show();
}else $('.error').append('Not Valid');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand what you trying to achieve..
You should place a span or any other text container next to your input field, static or dynamicly.

Maybe something like this (pseudo-ish code):

```
inputs.each( function() {

    if($(this).val().length<=0) 
    {
        valid = false;  
        // get the sibbling text container
        $(this).next().text("Invalid").show();             
    }
});
```